# How to compute MxN correlation matrix

Tags: python, dataframe, correlation, cross-correlation, pearson-correlation

I have a CSV file contains some tweets and two sets of features (A and B), as follows:

```
TWEET, A1, A2, B1, B2, B3
tweet text, 0.23, 0.54, 120, 60, 39
tweet text, 0.33, 0.7, 70, 20, 36
tweet text, 0.8, 0.41, 68, 52, 29
```

As you see they have different lengths (2 columns for A features, and 3 columns for B features). I want to compare their relationship (or dependence) to each other. My goal is to identify dependent features to remove some and reduce feature dimensions. One possible solution is to use a `correlation matrix`, which is accessible with `DataFrame.corr` . But this matrix only accepts arrays of the same size. The question is how can I compute the `correlation matrix` of different length features, like A and B in the above example? After correlation, I will be able to say, for example, that features A1 and B2 are sufficient enough and we can remove other features; Because they are completely dependent on A1 and B2.

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Just take all the 5 columns and plot correlation. You will have all possible combinations.

Comment: Could you please give me a tiny example of implementation? (related URL is also sufficient)

Comment: Added an answer hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correlation doesn't need to be MxN. all you are doing is checking correlation between `N` columns so it will be `NxN` matrix. From the `N*N` you can consider the ones which you like and neglect the others.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''TWEET, A1, A2, B1, B2, B3
tweet text, 0.23, 0.54, 120, 60, 39
tweet text, 0.33, 0.7, 70, 20, 36
tweet text, 0.8, 0.41, 68, 52, 29
'''),sep=',')
print(df.corr()) # Pandas correlation matrix
sns.heatmap(df.corr(),annot = True)
```

**Output:**

```
    A1              A2          B1         B2          B3
A1  1.000000    -0.732859   -0.661319   0.167649    -0.991352
A2  -0.732859   1.000000    -0.025703   -0.793614   0.637235
B1  -0.661319   -0.025703   1.000000    0.628619    0.754036
B2  0.167649    -0.793614   0.628619    1.000000    -0.036827
B3  -0.991352   0.637235    0.754036    -0.036827   1.000000
```

[image]